# CSS selectors not working after AngularJS upgrade

Tags: angularjs, selector, directive

I've migrated an AngularJS application from version 1.2.26 cu 1.5.11 and I'm having some troubles with selectors.

In a directive I have this piece of code:

```
var menu = element.find('.menu-list');
var menuWidth = menu.innerWidth();
var menuItem = menu.find('li').width(menuWidth);
```

Where `element` refers to the element attribute from the `link` function.

After migration, this code throws an error saying: `TypeError: menu.innerWidth is not a function`

What do I need to modify in order to make the code work again?

Comment: According to the documentation `Keep in mind that this function will not find elements by tag name / CSS selector. For lookups by tag name, try instead angular.element(document).find(...) or $document.find(), or use the standard DOM APIs, e.g. document.querySelectorAll().` This appears to be newer in 1.5, but not the case in 1.2. Perhaps you can try `$document.find()` or `document.querySelector`

Comment: But I don't want to search for the element in the DOM, I want to limit the search to the directive.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery before loading Angular in your HTML? That will determine whether `element` is a jQuery object or a jqLite object, and whether `innerWidth` is available.